# Quantum defect and non-alkali atoms

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

Let's consider a generic multi-electron atom. We know that, as an approximation, the energy of a particular electron in the atom is given by $E_{n,l} \sim -\frac{Z_{\text{eff}}^2}{n^2}$, where $Z_{\text{eff}}$ is the effective nuclear charge, which depends on $n$ and $l$. I also know that, for an alkali atom (Li, Na, K, ...), we can write $E_{n,l} \sim -\frac{1}{(n-\delta_{n,l})^2}$ where $\delta_{n,l}$ is the quantum defect, which depends quite esclusively by $l$.

**My question**: Is it possible to use the quantum defect also for non-alkali atoms? I searched online and I only found that the quantum defect is used for alkali atoms.

Thank you.